# how to insert xml data in db using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

my xml format is like this

<Section SectionNumber="0">

<Text Name="Text12"><TextValue>Total Scripts:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Text Name="Text14"><TextValue>Packs:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="Field24" FieldName="{@Packs}"><FormattedValue>0.02</FormattedValue><Value>0.02</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field3" FieldName="Sum ({Command.QUANT}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>20</FormattedValue><Value>20.00</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field4" FieldName="{Command.NDC}"><FormattedValue>00406-0484-10</FormattedValue><Value>00406-0484-10</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field5" FieldName="{@DrugName}"><FormattedValue>ACETAMINOPHE/CODEINE 300-30MG TAB</FormattedValue><Value>ACETAMINOPHE/CODEINE 300-30MG TAB</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field18" FieldName="Count ({Command.RXNO}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></Field>

<Text Name="Text17"><TextValue>Total For:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="SumofGTotRxAmt1" FieldName="Sum ({Command.GTotRxAmt}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>2.75</FormattedValue><Value>2.75</Value></Field>

<Text Name="lblSumOfInsPaid"><TextValue>Total Ins Paid:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="txtSumOfInsPaid" FieldName="Sum ({Command.TotInsAmt}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>1.75</FormattedValue><Value>1.75</Value></Field>

<Text Name="Text3"><TextValue>Total Price:</TextValue>

</Text>

</Section>

<Section SectionNumber="1">

</Section>

</GroupFooter>

</Group>

<Group Level="1">

<Details Level="2">

</Details>

<GroupFooter>

<Section SectionNumber="0">

<Text Name="Text12"><TextValue>Total Scripts:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Text Name="Text14"><TextValue>Packs:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="Field24" FieldName="{@Packs}"><FormattedValue>1.00</FormattedValue><Value>1.00</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field3" FieldName="Sum ({Command.QUANT}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>60</FormattedValue><Value>60.00</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field4" FieldName="{Command.NDC}"><FormattedValue>00173-0697-00</FormattedValue><Value>00173-0697-00</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field5" FieldName="{@DrugName}"><FormattedValue>ADVAIR DISKUS 500-50MC EA</FormattedValue><Value>ADVAIR DISKUS 500-50MC EA</Value></Field>

<Field Name="Field18" FieldName="Count ({Command.RXNO}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue><Value>1</Value></Field>

<Text Name="Text17"><TextValue>Total For:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="SumofGTotRxAmt1" FieldName="Sum ({Command.GTotRxAmt}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>412.44</FormattedValue><Value>412.44</Value></Field>

<Text Name="lblSumOfInsPaid"><TextValue>Total Ins Paid:</TextValue>

</Text>

<Field Name="txtSumOfInsPaid" FieldName="Sum ({Command.TotInsAmt}, {Command.NDC})"><FormattedValue>412.44</FormattedValue><Value>412.44</Value></Field>

<Text Name="Text3"><TextValue>Total Price:</TextValue>

</Text>

</Section>

Comment: Are you looking to just store the raw xml?

Answer (score -1):

Escape XML string before insert in databse

Example

$xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml);